# Get Facebook mutual friends in Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

After searching stackoverflow and not finding solution of my problem I am posting this question.

My goal is to get facebook mutual friends in `Android` app. I used graph `API` query

```
    private void getAndDisplayMutualFriends(final String fbId){

    Session myFbSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "context.fields(mutual_friends)");
    /* make the API call */
    new Request(
            myFbSession,
            "/{"+fbId+"}",
            params,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    Log.d("JSONRESPONSE","FB ID="+fbId);
                    Log.d("JSONRESPONSE",""+response.toString());
                }
            }
            ).executeAsync();
}
```

`fbId` is facebook Id of the friend with whom logged in user wants to get mutual friends But I get:

> {Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
>   404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803)
>   Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {100008114977883}},
>   isFromCache:false}

I am stuck at this from a week, logged in user, mutual friend and friend has given "user_friends" permission.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error response explains it well

Response: responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {100008114977883}}, isFromCache:false}

This alias `{100008114977883}` does not exist, remove the `{}`